# Kotlin + React pecents in html and media-reqests

Tags: html, css, reactjs, kotlin

How can i realize margin or padding etc. by auto or percentage use like  `margin : auto;` via kotlin language?

How can i realize @media-requests via kotlin language?

UPD:
To be clear: How to realize this constructions:

```
margin : auto;
```

or

```
margin: 5%;
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Be sure to show what you've tried, and give some context for your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

`margin = Auto.auto`

or

`margin = 5.pct`

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot. Can you help with `@media`-requests? It not in the docs too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
    css {
        margin: "auto",
        margin: "5%",
    }
    h3 {
        +"John Doe: Building and breaking things"
    }
    img {
        src = "https://via.placeholder.com/640x360.png?text=Video+Player+Placeholder"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. Look at the update please

Comment: ok, I updated my answer. I hope it works.

Comment: No it's not working.